# Driving optocoupler by a line receiver

Tags: opto-isolator, driver, differential

I wanna drive TLP350 by a line receiver AM26LS32. I employed scheme 1, however, there was no signal on output.
I  found in line receiver datasheet that the current sign is negative so it is likely to be a sink output. Thus I implemented
scheme 2. Yet again there is not any output. I prepared a square wave with voltage from 0V to 2V at input of TLP350 and it works fine. The output of AM26LS32
is also correct with amplitude of 4V. Now I almost sure there is something with driving TLP350 by the line receiver for example
insufficient load current or something like this. Could you please help me what the problem is?
**Pins for AM26LS32:** pin **14** as B, **15** as /B, and **13** as Bout.

[image]

Comment: the AM26LS32 datasheet from TI does not list a /B terminal

Comment: I meant pin 14 as B, 15 as /B, and 13 as Bout.

Comment: Let me see.  AM26LS32 is 5V tristate output. So to troubleshoot, we can put it aside, and by hand use a jumper wire to input 5V and 0V tp TLP350 LED anode (Pin 2), with Cathode Pin3 connected to ground.

Comment: As I mentioned before `I prepared a square wave with voltage from 0V to 2V at input of TLP350 and it works fine.` So TLP350 does work.

Comment: Now let us see the input current to the TLP350 LED. (1) If = 5V / 500R = 5000/500 mA = 10mA, which is big enough to trigger the photo transistor at the output side.

Comment: Yes it is triggered by input voltage more than 2V. (2V to 5V)

Comment: (1) Since TLP350 output is Totem Pole, so no load is needed to test output. (2) Vcc 24V is with range of 15~30. So if input to TLP350 is 5V High, 0V Low, you can use a multimeter to check put the the output is 0V, 24V. (3) If your square wave input is 0V/2V, and output looks OK, then I agree with you that TLP350 should be working properly.

Comment: But wait a second. If your square wave High input is only 2V, then If is only 2V/500R = 4mA, might not be big enough. So I would suggest to use a 5V/0V square wave signal.

Comment: Perhaps you can increase your square wave amplitude from 2V to 4V (AM26LS32) in your case.

Comment: it is already 4V. I just input a 2V input to obtain what the minimum input voltage is for TLP350.

Comment: It would be nice if you can use a scope to display the wave forms at input and output side of TLP350. Just in case you might also like to give a small load of say 10k to TLP350. Good luck and cheers.

Comment: @Pana Did you forget to tie one or the other enable pin active to enable the AM26LS32 output?

Comment: Dear Justme as I mentioned `The output of AM26LS32 is also correct with amplitude of 4V.`. So it has been configured correctly. You worry about pin 4 (G) and pin 12 (/G). They are connected to 5V and GND, respectively.

Comment: @Justme Could you please tell which scheme is correct and supposed to work correctly?

Comment: Based on AM26LS32 output drive capability, circuit 2 sinks enough current and should work, circuit 1 can't source enough current and won't work.

Comment: Usually the line driver goes directly connected to the opto, without line receiver. You will find this method in almost every servo driver, VFD, stepper motor driver,..etc. It makes no sense using an additional 5v supply that it should be also isolated in a receiving device.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič, Yes, I have seen it in many servo drivers documents. Yet the distance between differential signal generator and this board is rather long and the environment is noisy. So I reckon that maybe it is better to use a line receiver to have a better signal.

Comment: @Justme Really I do not know why scheme 2 won't work. I am curious to find my mistake. By the way, I added a transistor between the line receiver and optocoupler in scheme 2 and it worked fine. Although it worked, it is a workaround not an answer to me!

Comment: Not needed. The line driver has low impedance and the LED + resistor, also low, the cable is twisted pair, so no noise will be introduced. The industrial drives works this way, so you might skip the complexity.. The receiver cold be used with a non-isolated approach.